# Firebase data not loading in list unless refreshed (angularJS, firebase & ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, firebase

My list of items are not loading properly. I get an empty screen with no errors and once I refresh, they all show up. I believe the firebase data is not being retrieved fast enough but I dont know what to do. I tried multiple things with no luck. Thank you in advance!

app.controller('SpotsCtrl', function($state, $scope, $stateParams) {

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myBrokenApp.firebaseio.com/spots");

firebaseRef.child('0').on('value', function(dataSnapshot){
    console.log("hello");

    $scope.spots = dataSnapshot.val();
    console.log($scope.spots);
})
```

});

//HTML

```
<ion-list show-delete="spot.showDelete" show-reorder="spot.showMove"> 

 <ion-item
     class="item-avatar-left item-icon-right item-remove-animate" 
       ng-repeat="spot in spots"
       href="#/tab/spots/{{spot.name}}">

      <h2>{{ spot.name }}</h2>
      <p>{{ spot.title }}</p>
      <p>{{ spot.loc }}</p>
      <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline "></i>

       <ion-delete-button ng-click="deleteSpot($index)" 
                        class="ion-minus-circled">
       </ion-delete-button>

      <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon"
       on-reorder="moveSpot(spot, $fromIndex, $toIndex)">

      </ion-reorder-button>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding you firebaseref to a $firebaseObject.

```
app.controller('SpotsCtrl', function($state, $scope, $stateParams, $firebaseObject) {

  var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myBrokenApp.firebaseio.com/spots");
  $scope.spots = {};
  var spots = $firebaseObject(firebaseRef.child('0'));

  spots.$loaded().then(function() {
    $scope.spots = spots;
    console.log($scope.spots);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, no luck with that :( Any other ideas??

Comment: Hmm, okay.. Try wrapping `firebaseRef.child('0').on('value', function(dataSnapshot){...` in a `$timeout(function(){ firebaseRef.child... });`

Comment: nope :/ once the screen loads, if the data isn't ready it just stays blank until i refresh

Comment: Try my initial answer, but adding `$scope.spots = {};`. Doesn't the `console.log()` write anything in the $loaded.then-function?

Comment: IT WORKED!! ahhh thank you so much!
.. just so i understand, why did that work?

Comment: Nice :)
I'm not sure really. I think angular just wants something to be declared first, before populating it with data from within an event ($loaded) that's not really coming from angular it self.
I looked at one of my old projects using angular and angularFire, and I saw that I had declared my variable first so I figured I had done that for a reason :)

Comment: @SarahYonig Please don't use `console.log()` for monitoring loading of AngularFire data. The [AngularFire documentation explicitly mentions that this is a bad practice and recommends putting `<pre>spots | json</pre>` in your HTML view](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro).

Comment: Generally, any time you use $loaded(), you've gone astray.